# How to create a custom border for US shape file using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis, arcmap, choropleth

Im trying to create a heat map using telerik choropleth map. Im currently using a shape file of the US states and I would like to create a thicker outline for each of the region like this:

[image]

It seems very simple, but I cant find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find direct solution from ArcGIS, You can duplicate the shapefile, overlay it on your choropleth, and plot it as a  transparent polygon with thicker border.